# Create Process.start for Multi batch file

Tags: c#, .net

I created a list in app.config to create one process for all

```
<appSettings>
    <add key ="Service1" value="C:\BatchFile\Batch"/>
    <add key ="Service2" value="D:\Dev\BatchFile2\Batch2"/>
    <add key ="Service3" value="C:\Users\aala\Desktop\BatchFile1\Batch1"/>
</appSettings>
```

And then I created a process in here code

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\BatchFile\Batch";
process.Start();
Console.WriteLine("Process is Start");
while (true)
{
    Thread.Sleep(2000);

    if (process.HasExited)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Process is Stopped");
        process.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Process is Restard");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("Process is running");
    }
}
```

My question is how can create one process for many of paths and when I put a new path in app.config automatically work in process because I have a lot of paths and I don't want to create code for each path?

Comment: For loop over all the paths? Just read from settings and iterate over them, creating the processes along the way.